# Python/AWS Lambda Function: How to view /tmp storage?

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Lambda functions have access to disk space in their own `/tmp` directories. My question is, where can I visually view the `/tmp` directory?

I’m attempting to download the files into the `/tmp` directory to read them, and write a new file to it as well. I actually want see the files I’m working with are getting stored properly in `/tmp` during execution.

Thank you

Answer (score 13):

You can't 'view' the /tmp directory after the lambda execution has ended.

Lambda works in distributed architecture and after the execution all resources used (including all files stored in `/tmp`) are disposed.

So if you want to check your files, you might want consider using EC2 or S3.

If you just want to check if the s3 download was successful, during the execution, you can try:

```
import os
os.path.isfile('/tmp/' + filename)
```

Comment: EC2 is more than checking files, if he only want a `/tmp` directory that he want to access, S3 is enough.

Comment: @joarleymoraes I am actually downloading files from S3 bucket, and want to temporarily store the downloaded files in the /tmp. Just want to make sure I'm actually using the /tmp directory. From the site `Each Lambda function receives 500MB of non-persistent disk space in its own /tmp directory.` Is there a way to view the /tmp directory while the lambda is executing?

Comment: ok, got it. How are you downloading the file ? The function that downloads the file should return the tmp filename.

Comment: @joarleymoraes Downloading like so: `s3client.download_file(bucket_name, obj.key, '/tmp/'+filename)`. Want to check if the files being downloaded are in fact being stored in that `/tmp` directory. I have no way of checking. The logs do not even show any errors.

Comment: You can simply check with: `os.path.isfile('/tmp/' + filename)`. You might want actually open the file and check the content as well. Use `with open('/tmp/' + filename) as fp:` syntax.

Comment: @joarleymoraes So would it be `print(os.path.isfile('/tmp/' + filename))`? And does that return true or false?

Comment: Edited the answer to include this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143422/discussion-between-ly-maneug-and-joarleymoraes).

Comment: this answer is a gem!

Comment: Danger: The files in /tmp  are (unfortunately) *not* disposed between executions. They are disposed when deploying the lambda, but they will persist between executions, and the space is shared between *all* executions. So unless you delete the files yourself after every execution, you will at some point run into disk space problems (limited to 512mb)!

Comment: print( os.listdir('/tmp/') )     <-- to see /tmp contents

Answer (score 2):

As previous answers suggested, you might want to create a `/tmp` directory in `S3 bucket` and download/upload your temp processing file to this `/tmp` directory before final clean up.

You can do the following (I'm not showing detailed process here):

```
import boto 
s3 = boto3.client("s3")
s3.put_object(Bucket=Your_bucket_name,Key=tmp/Your_file_name)
```

How you download your file from your `/tmp` is through:

```
s3.download_file(Your_bucket_name, Your_key_name, Your_file_name)
```

after you download files and process, you want to upload it again to `/tmp` through:

```
s3.upload_file(Your_file_name, Your_bucket_name, Your_key_name)
```

You can add your `/tmp/` in `Your_key_name`

Then you should be able to list the bucket easily from this [sample](http://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/radosgw/s3/python/#listing-a-bucket-s-content):

```
for key in bucket.list():
        print "{name}\t{size}\t{modified}".format(
                name = key.name,
                size = key.size,
                modified = key.last_modified,
                )
```

Make sure you keep your download and upload asynchronously by [this boto async package](https://github.com/seomoz/s3po#callbacks).

Comment: no I am actually downloading files from S3 bucket, and want to temporarily store the downloaded files in the /tmp. Just want to make sure I'm actually using the /tmp directory. From the site `Each Lambda function receives 500MB of non-persistent disk space in its own /tmp directory.`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a `S3` bucket to store the file and read it from the `AWS Lambda` function, you should ensure the AWS Lambda role has access to the `S3` bucket.