# Download a file from a url and save to lamdbda temp folder C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

How can I save in the lambda temp folder? To be able to save and get the file from the lambda temp folder.

Comment: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=174119

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python/AWS Lambda Function: How to view /tmp storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43768290/python-aws-lambda-function-how-to-view-tmp-storage)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write to temp folder just like you would to any other folder. The temp folder is located at /tmp

Following is a sample snippet for doing that

```
// Example #1: Write an array of strings to a file.
// Create a string array that consists of three lines.
string[] lines = { "First line", "Second line", "Third line" };
// WriteAllLines creates a file, writes a collection of strings to the file,
// and then closes the file.  You do NOT need to call Flush() or Close().
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"/tmp/someText.txt", lines);
```